# Replace NaN values with values from other table

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Please help.

My first table looks like:

```
id val1 val2
0  4    30
1  5    NaN
2  3    10
3  2    8
4  3    NaN
```

My second table looks like

```
id val1 val2_estimate
0  1    8
1  2    12
2  3    13
3  4    16
4  5    22
```

I want to replace Nan in 1st table with estimated values from column `val2_estimate` from 2nd table where val1 are the same. `val1` in 2nd table are unique. End result need to look like that:

```
id val1 val2
0  4    30
1  5    22
2  3    10
3  2    8
4  3    13
```

I want to replace `NaN` values only.

Answer (score 1):

Use `merge` to get the corresponding df2's estimate for df1, then use `fillna`:

```
df['val2'] = df['val2'].fillna(
    df.merge(df2, on=['val1'], how='left')['val2_estimate'])
df

   id  val1  val2
0   0     4  30.0
1   1     5  22.0
2   2     3  10.0
3   3     2   8.0
4   4     3  13.0
```

Many ways to skin a cat, this is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use fillna with map from a pd.Series created using set_index:

```
df['val2'] = df['val2'].fillna(df['val1'].map(df2.set_index('val1')['val2_estimate']))
df
```

Output:

```
    val1  val2
id            
0      4  30.0
1      5  22.0
2      3  10.0
3      2   8.0
4      3  13.0
```